# Component Process + Translation Workflow Process (review)

Tags: web8.5, workflow, translation-manager

While playing around with the [Translation Review](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E5C84985-24F5-4F7A-9124-34782EA667E0&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-38289FEA-BAC2-4FEE-8C8D-E5E0AA8770B7.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E5C84985-24F5-4F7A-9124-34782EA667E0&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtranslation%2520review&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1551282619020) functionality (last heading on the page), I've noticed that you cannot attach both a Components Process + 
Translation Workflow Process (review) to a [Schema](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E55F3782-38F2-4ADF-A30D-7B06CBB17CB5&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-9626D6F9-477B-4639-9B5E-8E5FD4FCA4D5.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E55F3782-38F2-4ADF-A30D-7B06CBB17CB5&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtranslation%2520review&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1551282619020&currentQuery=translation%2520review&currentScope=).

Tridion has a limitation that if a Translation Workflow Process is set to a Schema or Structure Group, you cannot add a Component Process/Page Process respectively. The error displayed is:

> Schema or Structure group cannot have both "Translation Manager review workflow" and other kinds of workflows (Legacy workflow or Bundle workflow)

While I think I understand why this is, having the same item in 2 Workflows at the same time is counter-intuitive and might cause conflicts, this introduces some limitations.

Let's take the following scenario:

- I want to have a Component reviewed within Tridion upon creation/modification. To do this, I would set a Component Process with a Review step and assign it to the relevant group. (Or do it via a Bundle process)
- When the Component is sent to translation, I want to be able to use the Translation Review feature to see the translation from the used TMS.

These should be triggered in different stages so the only thing that comes to mind is:

- to set the "Tridion Review" Process on a lower level
- localize the Schema and set the Translation Workflow Process in the Publication where I'm sending the Components to review.

However, this requires me to have an additional layer of Blueprinting just for this purpose + introduces maintainability complications for maintaining the Schema (field changes that need to be applied to two levels).

Is there a better approach? Can I somehow combine the two workflow functionalities into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decision to not allow two WF processes comes from inability of CM to run two WF processes. It is also ambiguous how to orchestrate running one process after another since we do not know what need to be run when. If it need to run in same publication.

Original idea was to configure Translation Review process only in target publication.

You don't really need extra layer of blueprint, you can localize schema in target publication and set Translation review process there. And I believe localized schemas still automatically synchronize field changes from parent schemas.

However I can see how it can be annoying to localize all schemas in all target publications especially if you have lots of languages.

We might to consider some improvements in the future. When Translation process set in source schema will apply to targets only.

For now there is nothing in product to help with this.

Except the fact that you can combine "Component review" and "Translation review" processes in to one. In fact Translation review process can be augmented with any other workflow steps. Also it is possible to set "Translation review process" in to "Associated Component Process" (standard WF process) field.

The challenge here is of course that one part of process is executed in source publication and another in target publication. And process need to cater for both and know in which publication it is running.

[image]

By setting this kind of combined process in to "Associated Component Process" (standard WF process) field on source schema. You can get both review with one process.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, quite informative I might add. You're right, it's impossible to change the fields of localized schemas, totally slipped my mind, my bad.